# Create an function from data-frame column values and insert into blank elements of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (df) which looks like:

```
          FHE
0           1
1           1
2           1
3
4           1
5  0.77027027
```

I am trying to create a new column called FHE_TO_USE which copies the FHE column and creates the mean of the FHE column and fills in any blanks with the mean.  So the solution would look like:

```
        FHE     FHE_TO_USE
0           1            1
1           1            1
2           1            1
3               0.95405405
4           1            1
5  0.77027027   0.77027027
```

I've tried the folling without success:

```
df["FHE"] = np.where(df["PATTERN"]=="FT",1,df["FHE"])

df["FHE"] = df["FHE"].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

df["FHE_TO_USE"] = np.where(df["FHE"]=="",statistics.mean(df["FHE"]),df["FHE"])
```

This also gives me a future warning:

```
FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  To re-infer data dtypes for object columns, use Series.infer_objects()
For all other conversions use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.
```

What is the correct way to create the mean?

Comment: `df.FHE.fillna(df.FHE.mean())`?

Comment: Its necessary to cast to numeric, having strings @QuangHoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `fillna()`:

```
df['FHE'] = pd.to_numeric(df.FHE, errors='coerce')
df['FHE_TO_USE'] = df.FHE.fillna(df.FHE.mean())
```

Result:

```
       FHE  FHE_TO_USE
0  1.00000    1.000000
1  1.00000    1.000000
2  1.00000    1.000000
3      NaN    0.954054
4  1.00000    1.000000
5  0.77027    0.770270
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting the Future Warning, do you know how I can get rid of that console output?

Comment: To cast to numeric you have to use `pd.to_numeric`. As the warning suggests. `astype(float)` will fail